# Display sum with commas

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called `sum` in my (mysql) database. This column has the type `decimal(7,2)`. I am using the following statement to select the value from the database:

```
SELECT name, CONCAT('€ ', sum) as sum FROM payments
```

The sum is displayed like `€ 1000000.00`.

Is it possible to display the data like `€ 1,000,000.00`?

Does someone know how I can display the data like `€ 1,000,000.00`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use `format()`:

```
SELECT name, CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(sum, 2)) as sum
FROM payments
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the format function:

```
   SELECT name, CONCAT('€ ', FORMAT(sum, 2)) as sum FROM payments;
```

I also found a similar question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39419/mysql-format-numbers-with-comma

I hope this could be helpful. :D